# IntelliJ 10.5 on Ubuntu - Caret is broken (it keeps scrolling down as I scroll my screen downwards)

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a long file inside intelliJ (java, properties, ruby)  if I leave my caret on Line 1 and scroll down to line 300, then the caret keeps on scrolling down with my screen as i keep scrolling down.  Is this a bug or a setting of IntelliJ?

I am scrolling down using my mouse, and then also using my TrackPad.  This happens for me inside IntelliJ on Mac AND on ubuntu, so im guessing it's either a bug, or a feature.

Comment: How are  you scrolling down, mouse wheel, drag scroll bars, page down key?

Comment: @CrackerJack9, I am using the mouse scroller wheel and the trackpad as well.

Comment: I think that's a default behavior of Mac, try opening it in a normal text editor and scrolling down and see if the caret behaves similarly.

Comment: @CrackerJack9 - I opened up TextEdit and this is actually not the default behavior on the Mac, the caret always stays put in its rightful place. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was the vim plugin that was causing this problem.  Once I uninstalled it, everything began working.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.  I thought it wouldn't, because I had IdeaVIM in the disabled state.  I had to entirely uninstall the IdeaVIM plugin in order to prevent these side-effects.  To uinstall the IdeaVIM from IntelliJ Idea, I closed my project, selected "open plugin manager", searched for IdeaVIM, then right clicked and uninstalled it.  After restaring IntelliJ Idea, all was well again.

Comment: Thanks a lot - would never have found it. Sneaky Problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem in any application (also in Windows), but only with my laptop (Thinkpad). If I just touch the trackpad, it stops scrolling. Not a real solution, but just a workaround that has helped me a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

I also see the same problem in my IntelliJ Idea. I fixed it by enable Vim plugin - restart my Idea - disable Vim plugin. Then it fixed. Only disable Vim maybe not work. You can tray these 3 steps to active this change to let Idea know.